# What is the difference between ?? and =?? in Dart?

Tags: dart, singleton

In the code below to implement the Singleton design pattern, we approach two different ways.
One of them creates `Singleton` but the other creates an object each time we call it.
What's the difference between `??` and `=??` in the code below written in dart?

```dart
class ExampleStateByDefinition extends ExampleStateBase {
  static ExampleStateByDefinition? _instance;

  ExampleStateByDefinition._internal() {
    initialText = 'A new "ExampleStateByDefinition" instance has been created.';
    stateText = initialText;
    print(stateText);
  }

  static ExampleStateByDefinition? getState() {
    return _instance ?? ExampleStateByDefinition._internal();     //here we use ??
  }
}
```

The above code creates an object each time we call it, so let us look at another variant:

```dart
class ExampleStateByDefinition extends ExampleStateBase {
  static ExampleStateByDefinition? _instance;

  ExampleStateByDefinition._internal() {
    initialText = 'A new "ExampleStateByDefinition" instance has been created.';
    stateText = initialText;
    print(stateText);
  }

  static ExampleStateByDefinition? getState() {
    _instance ??= ExampleStateByDefinition._internal();        //Here we use ??=
    return _instance;
  }
}
```

The above code implements Singleton by definition in [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `??=` operator is a compound assignment operator.
Just like `target += 1` is equivalent to `target = target + 1` (but with `target` only evaluated once, if it's a complicated expression),
`target ??= expression` is equivalent to `target = target ?? expression` (but with `target` only evaluated once *and* the assignment not even happening if `target` is non-`null`).

So, the difference is that the first code probably doesn't work, the second one does.

The code:

```dart
 return _instance ?? ExampleStateByDefinition._internal();
```

checks whether `_instance` is non-`null`, and if so, it returns the value of `_instance`. If it is `null`, it evaluates and returns `ExampleStateByDefinition._internal()`.
*No-where in that does it assign to `_instance`.* So, `_instance` is always going to be `null`, and the code is probably failing to do what it intended to do—caching a value.

The code:

```dart
 _instance ??= ExampleStateByDefinition._internal();  
 return _instance;
```

or its more streamlined version:

```dart
 return _instance ??= ExampleStateByDefinition._internal();
```

will also check if `_instance` is `null` and return its value if it isn't.
If `_instance` is `null`, it also evaluates `ExampleStateByDefinition._internal();`, and *then it assigns it to `_instance`*, and returns the value.

The next time you come around, `_instance` will be non-`null`, and the lazy caching works.

Answer (score 1):

Both `??` and `??=` are ***null-aware** operators*.

### Difference

The difference between the two operators is that the former only *evaluates* an expression while the latter also **assigns** the result of the expression.

This is why your first sample returns a new instance each time since you never *assign* it to your static variable.

#### `??`

> Use ?? when you want to evaluate and return an expression IFF another expression resolves to null.

The following expression:

```dart
exp ?? otherExp;
```

Is similar to this expression:

```dart
((x) => x == null ? otherExp : x)(exp);
```

#### `??=`

> Use ??= when you want to assign a value to an object IFF that object is null. Otherwise, return the object.

The following expression:

```dart
obj ??= value;
```

Is similar to this expression:

```dart
((x) => x == null ? obj = value : x)(obj);
```

See [Null-aware operators in Dart](http://blog.sethladd.com/2015/07/null-aware-operators-in-dart.html) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [dart tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour).

**To assign** only if the assignment to the variable is null we use `??=` operation.

`expr1 ?? expr2` if expr1 is not null, return its value; otherwise, **evaluates** and return the value of expr2.

Cause `??` operation evaluates each time we call the object, it creates a new object.